# Как обработать полученный POST запрос от сервера на c#

Tags: c#, xml

я отправляю запрос и получаю вот такой ответ:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<requestNum>PAY</requestNum>
<terminalNum>123456</terminalNum>
<resultCode>0</resultCode>
</response>
```

Мне нужно на основе полученного ответа поставить условие если  0 то вывести какое то сообщение. я получаю ответ в консоль и как это сделать в консоле не знаю.... (я только начинаю программировать, поэтому может я задаю не корректный вопрос)

Comment: Это же обычный XML, достаточно базового [XDocument](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load#System_Xml_Linq_XDocument_Load_System_String_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как пример:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlstring);
XmlNodeList nd = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/response/resultCode");
foreach (XmlNode n in nd)
{
   if(n.InnerText=="0")
     MessageBox.Show("какое то сообщение");
}
```

Если этот хмл всегда такой вид имеет
то достаточно обработать только одну ноду без фора

```
var text =doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/response/resultCode").InnerText;
```

Если этот хмл имеет 100% такой вид, то можно наплевать на xml и найти текст.

```
if(xmlstring.IndexOf("<resultCode>0</resultCode>")>=0)//Точное совпадение нужной строки
            MessageBox.Show("какое то сообщение");
```

Comment: ответ который я получаю от внешнего сервера выводиться в консоль, как можно не сохраняя ответ в xml файл, а обработать сразу в консоль

Comment: вместе MessageBox.Show, Console.WriteLine и используйте этот код для обработки xml. в  xmlstring - должен быть ваш ответ от сервера

Comment: Огромное спасибо!